# C++ Circular dependency error

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, circular-dependency

I swear I've solved this problem before, but I for the life of me can't seem to get this working using GCC 4.7.3.

I have classes that need to be rather circular,

casexponent.h

```
#ifndef CASEXPONENT_H
#define CASEXPONENT_H

class  CasExpression ;

class CasExponent {
  private:
   CasExpression * e;//this is a test.  

 };

 #endif
```

casexpression.h

```
#ifndef CASEXPRESSION_H
#define CASEXPRESSION_H

#include "casobject.h"


#include <vector>
class CasExponent ;

class CasExpression {
 private:
    CasExponent * exponent; //making this a pointer so that it isn't auto-initialized; 


};
#endif
```

The error I'm getting when trying to compile is:

```
 src/classes/casexponent.cpp:5:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
```

Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

I feel quite silly.  If I had paid closer attention to the compiler error, it was pointing to the source file, not the header, and if I had checked those, I'd have found the problemmatic trailing '}'.

Comment: It would help if you showed the indicated code. You showed some headers but the compiler message clearly points to a source file!

Comment: And therein lies the problem...I had an extra }.  I feel genuinely silly.